# Session timeout automatically close iframe window

Tags: iframe

I am trying to have a session timeout for an iframe window to automatically close after 20 minutes without warning is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is the code for your aim

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateIframe(){
var iframe=document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("src","http://www.disney.com");
iframe.setAttribute("id","target");
iframe.setAttribute("height","200");
iframe.setAttribute("width","200");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
setTimeout(function(){
var frame = document.getElementById("target");
if(frame!=undefined && frame !=null){
frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
  }
else{
console.log('Iframe not created yet');
}},20000);}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="CreateIframe()" >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm happy whene I can help anyone from the globe i wish it be a useful for you yes you can modify as you want

Comment: 200px for width and height you can put anyvalue you want

Comment: the second Argument from the setTimeOut Function accept time by milisecond also 1 second ==1000 milisecond and 1 minute =1000000 milisecond and 20 minute == 20 000 000 ms